# I have a question about the X-bar tree of a VP "ask Mary if she can come"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, linguistics

I know the structure for "ask if she can come" is "V': V CP", but how about "ask Mary if she can come"?

[image]

Comment: I would really like for there to be a place for this on the web somewhere, but sadly ELU is not it. Even [Linguistics.SE] has a specific close reason in order to _not_ allow questions about specific phrase structures.

Comment: You should get an answer on Linguisitics, X-Bar theory stuff is pretty standard over there, but not here, where descriptive grammar is the order of the day.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I will search for the answer on Linguistics.

Comment: Linguistics doesn't do trees, because (a) there are no standard trees (not even in X' theory), (b) there is no agreement on proper parsing, and (c) there is no standard software for making or editing trees. Trees are useful only for publishing papers, and if you're doing that already you don't need this SE. They are not really communicative.